# Linking libraries compiled with different version of gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, compatibility

I have a C++ software (Borealis stream engine) which is compiled and works with GCC 3.3.6 (I haven't been able to make it work with newer version of GCC, and there is no longer support for the software).

I like to extends this to call some complex cryptographic libraries (Pairing Based library) which is definitely compiled with the latest version of GCC.

My question is whether it is possible to do that, i.e. to call a library compiled with a new version of GCC from the code compiled with much older version of GCC? Is it technically possible? What are the potential problems?

I hope someone can help shedding some lights on these questions, so that I can avoid spending days (or even weeks) compiling and learning how to use these software just to find out at the end that they cannot work together.

Answer (score 1):

It is. If it wasn't, we would have serious problems. The version of the compiler is unrelated to the ABI of the platform.

(One thing that may actually break in the case of C++ compilers is a change in the name mangling convention, but, for example, with C, even this risk is nonexistent.)

Comment: [The C++ interface has evolved throughout the history of the GNU C++ toolchain. With each release, various details have been changed so as to give distinct versions to the C++ interface.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) You'll note that the version of libgcc.so changes between GCC versions, in order to identify when the ABI is imcompatible, and this is the case between 3.x and 4.x, _on some platforms_.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel Yeah. See the parenthesized part of the answer.

Comment: Yes, I read your answer. Now read my comment, and the site I linked to.